# Regex to match this

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to capture from PHPUnit output the file path and the error line with a condition.

- I don't want want lines that contain the *whole word* exception (can I exclude multiple words?).

This is my output and non-working (obviously:) pattern:

```
/path/includes/exception.php:7
/path/things-i-care-about/es/somefile.php:132
/path/things-i-care-about/es/somefile.php:121
/path/things-i-care-about/es/somefile.php:54
/path/things-i-care-about/es/somefile.php:60
/path/things-i-care-about/es/somefile.php:41
/path/things-i-care-about/es/somefile.php:47
/path/things-i-care-about/testfile.php:26

Pattern: /((?!exception).*.php):(\d.*)/gs
```

What I tried is negating any line that has "exception" in it, but my regex didn't quite work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit my answer to try to clarify.

Comment: This regex is used by sublime build file-regex , so according to the docs, it uses [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this pattern:

```
^(?:[^e\n]+|\Be|\be(?!xception\b))+\.php:\d+$
```

or this pattern, if you don't need to check a specific line format:

```
^(?>[^e\n]++|\Be|\be(?!xception\b))+$
```

Notice: If you need to select all consecutive lines in one block, you just need to remove `\n` from the character classes.